# Динамический select

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Помогите разобраться.

Изначально на форме есть один select(у него id = area). При выборе каког-либо элемента нужно добавить ещё один select(у него id = region). С первым следующий код работает:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#area').on('change', function () {
        getRegions(host, $(this).val());
    });

    $('#region').on('change', function () {
        console.log("dqwd");
        getCities(host, $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Но когда выбираю во втором какой-то элемент, то событие change не отрабатывает. У меня есть предположение почему это может быть. `

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Скорее всего из-за этой функции. Когда документ загрузился, элемента с id region ещё нет и потом оно не отработает.

Что можно сделать с этим? Как заставить отработать событие change по второму select?

Comment: ну так и вызывайте добавление слушателя после создания второго инпута

Comment: Прошу прощения, немного не понял по поводу слушателя.

Comment: Вам в принципе уже господин Igor ответил то же самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Добавлять обработчик `$('#region').on('change',` после создания второго селекта.

или

2. Использовать делегирование

   ```
   $(document).on('change', '#region', function () {
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, делегирование помогло.